# Where is "hide file names" options on Windows 10?

Tags: windows, windows-10

I wish to hide file names on my OneDrive images folder.

This is how I'd hide in windows 7

[image]

There is no such option on windows 10.

- I'm workin o a OneDrive synced filder.
- I Also set the folder customization as 'Pictures'

Comment: I've never come across that option in View... are you certain a 3rd party program or manual registry edit didn't create that?  Either of those options seems likely, especially if it disappeared after one of the bi-annual updates since these specific updates are similar in process to a repair install of Windows.

Answer (score 2):

The feature has disappeared in Fall Creators Update.

After doing some research I found out, that it is not possible to somehow reactivate it. I also dont know why the developers have made this strange decision.

Comment: .